# executing Newman through jenkins fails connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: rest, jenkins, npm, postman, newman

When i execute newman in a jenkins job it fais with this error "connect ECONNREFUSED ip "
[image: Result of jenkins job]

but when i execute the same commande in command line it works
[image: command line execution Result]